# Usage of break statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, break

I have a nested for and if structure as in below:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i!=j:
            if i<j:
                if i!=0 and j!=0:
                    if max==saving[i,j]:
                        c1 = i
                        c2 = j
```

I want to break all of the if conditions and for loops when c1 and c2 are found. 
Where should I use "break" control ? 
Thanks.

Comment: if `i < j` then `i != j` is *also* true.

Comment: In fact none of the conditionals are needed if the ranges for `i` and `j` are chosen more carefully.

Comment: You have redundant if statements which you could combine into one and when you find c1 and c2 just put a `break` in the next line and it will exit from the most recent for loop.
Please do some research before posting questions here. This is explained in the documentation at http://docs.python.org

Comment: and one more comment - `break` is used for for loops, not for if conditions. `break` has nothing to do with if.

Comment: `for i in range(1, n):`, `for j in range(i + 1, n):` would give you loops that make all your conditions expect the last one obsolete. There is probably a *better method* to look for a given value in a `numpy` two-dimensional array, however.